# Why is the header not in the center?

Tags: html, css, web, styles

I want the header of a paragraph to be centered, but I can´t get it working.

The whole and the paragraph have the property `text-align:left` and the header has `text-align:center` but still it´s not centered.

```css
body{
  text-align:center;
}
main{
  text-align:left;
}
b{
  text-align:center !important;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <b>Header:</b>  
</main>
```

Can somone give me some advice what I´m doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Put an [mcve] **in the question itself**. Answers shouldn't depend on external sites to be understood. [Stackoverflow supports live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: `b` is inherently an `inline` element. You need to declare it as a `block` element, or wrap it in an element that is inherently a `block` element, like `p, div, h1`, etc.

Comment: Why you are adding text align left to p?

Comment: I feel sorry for anyone that answered this question

Comment: Who is serial downvoting answers here and why?

Comment: Why are all answers (even working ones) downvoted here?

Comment: @FatTony Probably because questions as badly researched as this one are not worth answering.

Comment: Still downvoting doesn´t make any sense if the answer is correct. If the question is bad, just downvote the question itselfe and don´t punish the answerers.

Comment: @MrLister That's a bad excuse for a downvote if I've ever heard one. If someone believes that, then they can move on, they are contributing nothing by downvoting correct answers from folks who have taken the time or made any sort of effort to provide an answer

Comment: I'm astonished that there are so many answers and none that are good. There are having several which mention using different markup (mostly `<div>` — the block element of last resort), but none that talk about how to select good markup. Nobody has pointed out that a heading should use one of the heading elements instead of a bold element. No answer bothers to explain about what `text-align` actually does. (UncaughtTypeError's answer comes *close* to doing both, but doesn't quite get there). The question should be closed, not answered, anyway.

Comment: @FatTony — Because the question should be closed, not answered. Try reading to the end of my previous comment.

Comment: @Quentin if enaugh people are the opinion it should be closed it will be. As long as this isn´t the case, just let people that want to help try to help.

Comment: @FatTony — I'm not stopping them.

Comment: @Quentin still instead of writing the correct answer, that you are claiming to know, you criticise the ones that actually try to help. If in your opinion this question should be closed just leave it.

Comment: @Quentin So long as it's opened it'll receive answers. You're not stopping anyone but you are helping anyone either - and if it's not your intention to help in any way that is constructive you are not making a positive contribution or impact to this thread and should consider retaining your downvotes and opinions.

Comment: @FatTony — If criticising is so wrong, why are you criticising my comments?

Comment: @Quentin Criticising isn´t wrong, but if you criticize the answers are wrong, and you know the correct one, you should also post the correct answer!

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError — My comments are considerably more helpful that you're telling me not to make them. You probably shouldn't speculate about who is downvoting what, you're probably wrong about it.

Answer (score 3):

Put a `div` around it. The `<b>` tag cannot be centered.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  text-align: left;
}

.header {
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="header">
    <b>Header:</b>
  </div>

</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

A `<b>` element is `display: inline` by default.

The [`text-align` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#alignment-prop) says: *Applies to:     block containers*.

It therefore has no effect on a `<b>` element by default.

You need to apply it to a block container instead. There are three ways to do this:

- Find (or add) an ancestor element which is a block container
- Change the `<b>` (using the CSS `display` property) so that it is a block
- Replace the `<b>` with a different element which is a block.

In this case, the apropriate thing to do is to replace the `<b>`.

You should select markup based that describes *what content is* and not *how it should look*. (This has been true since CSS 1 was released in 1996 and began the process of separating style from structure in webpages).

You have been calling the element "the header". HTML provides elements specifically for that purpose.

Aside from [the `<header>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header) itself, there are the [`<h1>` - `<h6>` heading elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements).

You content makes it look like an `<h1>` would be appropriate.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Header</h1>
</main>
```

You can also remove the `!important` flag. It is usually more trouble than it is worth and provides no benefit here.

Answer (score 0):

[`header`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-header-element) seems a better tag to group "introductory or navigational aids...heading elements but also other elements like a logo, a search form, and so on.", [documentation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header).

[`main`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-main-element) would be better suited for "content...unique to the document, excluding any content that is repeated across a set of documents such as sidebars, navigation links, copyright information, site logos, and search forms (unless the document's main function is as a search form).", [documentation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main).

To be clear, `text-align` property is inherited by child elements, [documentation at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align).

That said, consider the following code:

```css
body{
  text-align: center;
}
header{
  text-align: left;
}
h1{
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Header:</h1>
  <p>Content in a paragraph (should be left aligned, inheriting from `header`)</p>
</header>
```

Answer (score -2):

A easy solution may be using positioning. Something like this:

```
body {
  text-align:center;
  position: relative;
}
main {
  text-align:left;
}
b {
  position: absolute;
  left: 45%;
}
```

Another solution would be to just

```
display: block
```

the `b` element.

Comment: That isn't easy. It's stupidly fragile that depends on guessing ratio of font size and content to the width of the container.

Comment: Ok then just put a "display: block" for the "b" element.

Answer (score -3):

You can not align b tag content.

Just change in your jsfidle like this.

html

```
<main>
 <p><b>Header:</b></p> 
</main>
```

and css

```
p{
  text-align:center !important;
}
```